# How to draw a rectangle when a mouse is dragged?

Tags: java, jpanel, mouselistener

I'm trying to draw a rectangle onto a selected image when a mouse is dragged.
It seems that mouse listener is working but a rectangle is not drawn along the mouse drag.

What my program will do is, open an image selection dialog when a "click" buttom is pressed then select an image(any). After the image is displayed on a new JPanel, click a mouse and drag it to draw a rectangle on the image.

If there is a better way to code the function, please tell me how, It will be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private GridBagLayout gbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;
    private Rectangle draggingRectangle;
    private boolean dragging;

    public Test() {
        dragging = false;
        constructPanel();
    }

    private void constructPanel() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(gbl);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton imageButton = new JButton("Click");
        imageButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
                jc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                if (jc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    displayImage(jc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbl.setConstraints(imageButton, gbc);
        panel.add(imageButton);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void displayImage(String filePath) {
        draggingRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0);
        dragging = false;

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JScrollPane scrPane = null;
                try {
                    JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel() {
                        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                            g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filePath), 0, 0, this);

                            // g.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);
                            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            if (dragging) {
                                g.drawRect(draggingRectangle.x, draggingRectangle.y, draggingRectangle.width,
                                        draggingRectangle.height);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    scrPane = new JScrollPane(imagePanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

                    scrPane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (draggingRectangle != null) {
                                System.out.println("pressed");
                                draggingRectangle.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 0, 0);
                                imagePanel.repaint();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                            dragging = false;
                            if (draggingRectangle != null) {
                                System.out.println("released");
                                draggingRectangle.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                                imagePanel.repaint();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });
                    
                    scrPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                            if (draggingRectangle != null) {
                                System.out.println("dragged");
                                int x = (int) draggingRectangle.getX();
                                int y = (int) draggingRectangle.getY();
                                draggingRectangle.setSize(e.getX() - x, e.getY() - y);
                                imagePanel.repaint();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            
                        }
                        
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                JFrame imageDisplay = new JFrame();
                imageDisplay.add(scrPane);
                imageDisplay.setSize(530, 200);
                imageDisplay.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I inserted a debug code to check whether the mouse listener is working.
and it's working.

Comment: Add the mouse listener to the image pane, not the scroll pane

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working as I wanted to.

Comment: "_If there is a better way to code the function, please tell me how, It will be much appreciated._" This sounds more like a code review question than an SO question. You might want to take a look at [the codereview.stackexchange.com guidelines](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) to see if your question _later_ fits there instead.